# Hadoop replace cp with Distcp

Tags: hadoop

The process is copying the files from one hdfs location into another location in SAME cluster. This is working fine but hadoop -cp is taking time. Can it be replace with distcp for same cluster. OR Is there any better solution to increase the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs distcp works with copying data within the cluster and between the clousters as well:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html

> DistCp Version 2 (distributed copy) is a tool used for large
>   inter/intra-cluster copying. (...) The most common invocation of
>   DistCp is an inter-cluster copy:
>
> `bash$ hadoop distcp hdfs://nn1:8020/foo/bar hdfs://nn2:8020/bar/foo`
>
> This will expand the namespace under /foo/bar on nn1 into a temporary
>   file, partition its contents among a set of map tasks, and start a
>   copy on each NodeManager from nn1 to nn2.